# Fetch error - Receiving 405 GET Method Not Allowed While Using POST

Tags: javascript, fetch, http-status-code-405

I am trying to deploy an app where I have to register to get a JSON with my data (`username`, `email`, `password`) from the backend. I linked the frontend to backend with a fetch (the code is attached). My fetch request has a POST method, but I get this error, whilst I am not using any GET method, why so?

```js
fetch('link/signup' /*will be changed with correct URL tomorrow*/,{
    method: 'POST',
    /* method: 'POST',
    body: formData, */
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username.value,
      email: email.value,
      password: password.value,
    }),
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
```

> GET https://link/signup/ 405 (Method Not Allowed) (anonymous) @
> registration.9bbdb929a0502d2a723f.js:68

Comment: GET https://link/signup/ 405 (Method Not Allowed) (anonymous) @ registration.9bbdb929a0502d2a723f.js:68

Comment: Cool, so: what does your dev tools network tab say is happening? 405 means that whatever "method" value you picked is not supported by the server, suggesting that `POST` is not recognized for the URL you're calling.

Comment: This is very weird, how shall I fix it?

Comment: by first updating your post to show what you _actually_ see =) Update your post with the dev tools information (do not add it as answer: if it's not an answer to you question, don't post it as answer) Also, protip: just blank sensitive information with black box. Don't yellow/blue draw over it.

Comment: did you fix it? how?

Answer (score -2):

It's weird, but some APIs are not case-sensitive. Try to write 'post' instead 'POST' and see